# null point exception when I try to open a file

Tags: java, servlets

I want to open a file with  servlet

I have a function which return this type byte[]

and I have a jps file which contain a button , when I click in this button this methode (consult) will be called 
I try this code

```
public class Test{

    private HttpServletRequest request;
      private HttpServletResponse response;

public void consult() {

        P8Connector connector = new P8Connector(TypeEnum.CE.value(),
                "test");


        GetDocumentsListInFolder getDocumentsListInFolder = new GetDocumentsListInFolder();
        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<Document>();

        list = getDocumentsListInFolder.execute(connector,
                "/test", "1");


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Document doc = (Document)list.get(i);
            GetDocumentContent c = new GetDocumentContent();
           byte[] is =  c.execute(connector , doc); 


   response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
         response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
          response.setContentType("application/pdf");
           InputStream in = new FileInputStream("20130114.008.01.pdf");
           OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

           // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           int len;
           while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
              out.write(buf, 0, len);
           }
           in.close();

}
 public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
          this.request = request;
          }

          public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest(){
          return request;
          }

          public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response){
          this.response = response;
          }

          public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse(){
          return response;
          }

}
```

but  when I run this code  I have

this erreur :  null point exception

in this line

```
   response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```

Comment: response is null. You will have to now find out why.

Comment: Did you debug to check if response is obtained correctly? It seems your problem is not with the open file action.

Answer (score 0):

Who call `setServletResponse` ? It seems nobody, so response is null.